# textgreek not working in scrbook class with artemisia

Tags: fonts, miktex, koma-script, greek

For some reason I cannot get `textgreek` to work with the `artemisia` option in `scrbook`.

My absolute MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 

\usepackage[artemisia]{textgreek}

\begin{document}
  \textepsilon
\end{document}
```

The *process exited with error(s)*.

In the log file it shows:

> !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file gartemisiarg6r): Font gartemisiarg6r at
>   611 not found

which is weird, as the file is located in my MiKTeX dirs at *C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\tfm\public\gfsartemisia\gartemisiarg6r.tfm*

The package `gfsartemisia` is installed and I have even reinstalled it.

PS: It works with `euler` and `cbgreek`, however I don't like the curvy letters of the former and the latter has pixelated edges.

Comment: Maybe you need to run the `updmap` stuff which MikTeX often fails to do.

Comment: If your system is uptodate and you have the new MiKTeX console you can run an entry in the tasks menu to recreate the font maps. You probably should do it in user mode.

Comment: @cfr Running `updmap.exe` in the \miketx\bin folder solved the problem. If you turn it into an answer, I will select it. Is `updmap` also called by the task menu in the MiKTeX Console?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Is there a duplicate? If not, would you write an answer, please? I don't know anything about MiKTeX!

Comment: @cfr Well... your solution was the one I tried and that worked. I would gladly accept your answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to improper installation of the software (updating the map files was needed)

Comment: @egreg The improper installation was not the users fault, but some problem within MiKTeX (see cfr's answer). And I did get an answer that I could not find anywhere else on the internet. Of couse, it is not a problem _within_ TeX or typesetting, but this was not clear, when the question was asked. And I believe, someone else might run into the same problem and be happy to find an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the xelatex compiler and in addition maybe you have to add the following in preamble:

```
\usepackage{xltxtra} 
\usepackage{xgreek} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\setromanfont{FreeSerif}
\setsansfont{FreeSans}
```